# Android Phonegap build screen resolution issue

Tags: android, cordova

I'm having trouble on my Android application generated by Phonegap.

Testing by Android Chrome, is correct. But when I generate the build the viewport appears too large.

Is it necessary to set something specific in my config.xml?

**Correct viewport**
[image: Correct Viewport]

**Incorrect viewport**
[image: Incorrect viewport]

Comment: How does your viewport look, please include it. For me it looks like an css issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing from the head Metatag the attribute "target-densitydpi = device-dpi".